# data not sorting

Tags: c#, datatable

The code below I am using to sort data in a datataable.. there are two different method I have tried and non of these methods actually work. Also order is DECS/ASC and colum is the index of the column I.E 10.

Does anyone have an idea to why this may be the case.

```
        string[] tosort = sortval.Split('-');
        string order = tosort[1];
        int colum = Convert.ToInt32(tosort[0]);
        DataView dv = new DataView();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = extractedData;
        string columnName = dt.Columns[colum].ToString();
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = columnName + " " + order;
      //  dv = dt.AsDataView();
      //  dv.Sort = dv.Table.Columns[colum].ColumnName + " " + order;
     //   dv.Sort = dv.Table.Columns[colum].ColumnName + " " + order;
     //   dt = dv.ToTable();
        extractedData = dt;
```

Comment: You have provided too little informations. Show sample data and the (incorrect) sort result and the value of `sortval`. Show the columns of your DataTable and their types.

Comment: But after setting the sort order on the DataView how do you extract the sorted values? You should loop on the DataView not the DataTable

Comment: What is in `sortval` at the start? DECS is a wrong value for the sort order DESC is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting doesn't alter the order of the data in the `DataTable` it is applicable to the view, so you should actually bind the `DataView` like `dt.DefaultView` or `dt.DefaultView.ToTable();`

Answer (score 1):

I am supposing a lot here, but if your sorting is correct then i think you are not looping correctly on your data:

```
 // This should follow the correct sort order
 foreach(DataRowView r in extractedData.DefaultView)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(r["colName"]);
 }
```

or, if you bind to a datagridview

```
dataGridView.DataSource = extractedData.DefaultView;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`DataView.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort.aspx) does not sort the underlying `DataTable` but it's `DataView`. So the rows in the table are in the same order as before.

You can use [`DataView.ToTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8ycds2f.aspx) to create a new `DataTable` from the result:

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = columnName + " " + order;
extractedData = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
```